# JButton not appearing on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have been trying to learn how to use layout manages in java, I have the following code that trys to add the class "StartButton", startbutton is just a class that extends JButton

When I run the code my JFrame is loaded properly and the JPanel is created, I also added a print to layoutItems() to insure that the function is being called.

This is my JPannel code;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class menuPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Color BG_COLOR = new Color(0xfaf8ef);


    private startButton startbutton;

    public menuPanel(){
        this.setOpaque(false);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
        this.setBackground(new Color(107, 106, 104));
        this.setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        startbutton = new startButton();

        layoutItems();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(BG_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
    }


    public void layoutItems(){
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        System.out.println("lol");
        c.weightx = 0.25;
        c.weighty = 0.175;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 6;
        this.add(startbutton, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be because you manually set your panel to visible before you added your component. Try revalidating your panel after adding the button

Comment: 1) `public void paint(Graphics g) { super.paint(g);` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g);` for any `JComponent`. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Don't override any painting method. A JPanel will already paint the background of the panel based on the Color specified in the setBackground(...) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding `paint` rather than `paintComponent` results in unpredictable behavior in the way that components are painted for any Swing component.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    ...
}
```

In fact overriding `paintComponent` isnt necessary as `setBackground(BG_COLOR)` will give the equivalent result

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the recommendation to call `pack()` on the class above as it does not work for JPanels. Instead, don't set your JPanel's size or preferred size -- let the components themselves and your layout managers do that. Then add all items to the JFrame, call `pack()` on it after adding all items, and then call `setVisible(true)` on it, in that order.

Oh, you will want to change your startbutton class name to **S**tart**B**utton since Java class names should begin with an upper case letter, and you should use camel-case names for all identifiers except constants.

If you're still stuck after trying out these recommendations, then consider creating and posting your [minimal code example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to review, test, and possibly fix.